# "The server did not provide a meaningful reply" with large message content

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I've just read lots of possibility to resolve the

> "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused
>   by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error"

WCF exception,

but none of them worked for me.
I have a service method which execute a linq query via EntityFramework and there is option for the user to enable or disable the load of the navigation properties. Here is the function.

```
public List<DataTransferObjects.Equipment> GetEquipments(bool Include = true)
{
    using (Entities.DBEntities context = new Entities.DBEntities())
    {
        return Include ? (from equipment
                          in context.Equipments
                          .Include(equipment => equipment.A)
                          .Include(equipment => equipment.B)
                          .Include(equipment => equipment.C)
                          .Include(equipment => equipment.D)
                          select equipment)?.ToDataTransferObjects<Entities.Equipment, DataTransferObjects.Equipment>().ToList()
                       :
                         (from equipment
                          in context.Equipments
                          select equipment)?.ToDataTransferObjects<Entities.Equipment, DataTransferObjects.Equipment>().ToList()
    }
}
```

When I call the function via the generated service reference with false Include value it works fine, but when the Include is true it throws the exception. I'm sure that the problem is the size of the message or some related size issue, because if I change the function to request the first 20 records it works fine (the whole table contains 94 records), so the working linq query.

```
(from equipment
 in context.Equipments
 .Include(equipment => equipment.A)
 .Include(equipment => equipment.B)
 .Include(equipment => equipment.C)
 .Include(equipment => equipment.D)
 select equipment).Take(20)?.ToDataTransferObjects<Entities.Equipment, DataTransferObjects.Equipment>().ToList()
```

The configuration is the following

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBinding" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
      <!--<security mode="Transport"> Nothing changed with this option
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>-->
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviour" name="ServiceLibrary.Service">
    <endpoint address="WCFService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.IService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things to think about

1. Both the client and server are responsible for setting config values for size and so forth, if you are worried about this type of thing, make sure the **client config** is set appropriately.
2. If you think its a size issue, just limit to one or a couple of records, this should give you a good indication.
3. My money is on is not being a size setting (`MaxReceivedMessageSize` error or something similar) and more likely a serialization problem in the one of the included nested contracts. Try implementing the includes one at a time to

   - Try and work out which related contract is causing the problem. It maybe just missing something simple.
   - Once again, try and start with something that works and keep adding more complexity until you find the problem

As a bonus tip, that is a total abuse of ternary operators and looks disgusting :) Just saying...

Good luck

Comment: I'm able to serialize the result list with the DataContractSerializer and the result as binary is an array with 1839955 length.

Comment: The client's config contains the same relevant attributes. I can request every single record with multiply messages but in this case the time overhead is significant, so the 1st message contains the first 20 records the 2nd message contains the second 20 records and so on. The best would be one message with every record.